# Page View Controller in xcode (choose each view controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Good morning,

I'm trying to develop my first iphone app and I would like to use the Page View Controller when the user choose the profile picture, his name, description (that counts 3 different view controllers).

I would like to know how can I implement a Page View Controller where I can choose which 3 views controlares are going to show (I have already created those 3 View Controllers) because I would like to use the navigation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am now sure if i've understood correctly, but you can create 3 IBActions (for your profile pic, name and description) and create 3 segues from this ViewController to the other 3 ViewControllers. 
Then, when the pic, name or description are tapped perform the correct segue that would go to the ViewController you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Container View. It is easy way to show the different view controllers.